# Tensorflow: How to pass output of a fully connected network into the same network for few time steps

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a **fully connected network** that takes input a vector of **N dimensions** concatenated along with a constant vector of **M dimension**, the output of the network is an **N dimension** vector. I want to feed this output again into the **fully connected network** and perform chaining for few iterations, after all the iterations, I want the loss gradients due to the last output to propagate through each iteration. Will simple looping by forming *TensorArray* of my ground truths do the job?Also, can anyone help me make a custom RNN cell that doesn't pass on the hidden states to the iterations following.